# Powershell: TCP Listener troubleshoot

Tags: powershell

I have made a Python script regarding the same process but I had to convert it to Powershel and I have some problems. First of all, the port 443 is used because it is the only port open and I want to do some SSL in the future. I also made a Ruby listener for a Linux Server, and it worked perfectly with Client Powershell, but I had to switch to a Windows Server and Powershell is the only option available. The script is way larger but I have issues only recieving the data.

**Client Script**

```
$test=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllBytes("C:\path\to\file.csv"))
$test2=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllBytes($env:computername));

$socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('XxX.XxX.XxX.XxX',443)

$stream = $socket.GetStream()
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024

$writer.WriteLine($env:computername)
$socket.close()
```

**Server Listener**

```
$LOCALHOST  = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry([Net.DNS]::GetHostName()).AddressList[0]
$PORT = "443"

$ENDPOINT = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint($LOCALHOST,$PORT) 
$TCPlistener = New-Object  System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $ENDPOINT
$TCPlistener.start() 

$DATA = $TCPlistener.AcceptTcpClient() 

$Stream = $DATA.GetStream() 
$Reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($Stream)
$Buffer = New-Object System.Byte[] 1024

while (($Element = $Stream.Read($Buffer,0,$Buffer.Length)) -ne 0) {

    $EncodedText = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $DATA = $EncodedText.GetString($Buffer,0, $Element)
    $sDecodedString=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($DATA))
    Write-Output $sDecodedString

}

# Closing stuff
$Reader.Close()
$Stream.Close()
$TCPlistener.Stop()
```

For some reason I cant read the $test2 variable in the server. Also, if I send $test, the one with the path to the CSV file it works almost perfect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really have a file in the current folder with name $env:computername?  [IO.File ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.8) is expecting a path to a file in order to read all bytes from it.  I suspect you may want `$test2 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Env:COMPUTERNAME))`

Comment: @leeharvey1 Sorry for late answer. I have tried with the command which you sent but the result is the same. I cant get any output in the server